# How do I choose appropriate fuse for my circuit?

Tags: dc-motor, protection, short-circuit, fuses, ac-dc

I am currently using a AC-DC adaptor with specs:

- AC-I: 100-2040V~50/60Hz 1.6A
- DC-O: 12V 5A

Which is powering up 8 DC motors,

- 4× 12V 6W
- 4× 12V (wattage not specified, the motor is meant to be attached to a car battery)

How do I determine what fuse to use, and where to place it?

Do I place it after the adaptor and before the motors? And which fuse to use?

Do I place it before the adaptor, onto the AC current? And which fuse to use?

Can I place a fuse at both places?

I'd like to proect the system against all possible over-current scenarios.

Comment: the question where to put it depends on what you want to protect. You're not saying that.

Comment: How can anyone tell you which fuse to use if you haven't even specified the normal and stall currents for the motors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect against all scenarios, you should put a fuse before and after the AC-DC adaptor.
Since motors draw large amounts of current for a short time when they start, it's difficult to calculate the value of the fuse exactly.
For the same reason I would suggest a power supply at least twice as many amperes as the motors would take. A reservoir capacitor could help too. Yet, depends on the type of motors.
I would strongly suggest glass fuse on holder clips so that they can be easily replaced.
On the AC side, you can use a 2A circuit breaker or replaceable fuses. Whatever is easier. A rail mounted  circuit breaker would require a wall mounted enclosure but it will be much more professional an installation. It can also be mounted in the main cabinet if you have a power line dedicated to it.

On the DC side I would put fuse holder clips for the standard 5*20mm. Buy a few different values. If you see that it blows too fast, put one with a higher value. You can fine-tune the exact amperage for your fuse to be as safe as possible.

I would not use resetable fuse unless the short condition will happen frequently and predictably without being a damageable condition.